# How to validate that at least one of two fields are present during serialization/deserialization

Tags: django, validation, serialization, django-rest-framework, deserialization

I am using Django Rest Framework and defining my Serializer class.
The input that the Serializer class is validating contains two fields like so:

```
"absolute_date_range":{
  "start":...,
  "end":...,
}

"relative_date_range"="last_7"
```

The user can choose to pass one or both of these in. But at least one of them has to be present. If not then it should result in a validation error.

The `required=True` condition works only on a single field. If I do this using custom logic, which is the best place to put this logic in - the Serializer or [in a Custom Field](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#custom-fields) or [Field level validation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation)?

How do I enforce this in my Serializer?

Comment: If you have a model with those fields, and the general requirement is to have at least one of the fields, then I'd say it's best to put the logic in the model. That would be DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) as it would avoid reimplementing the validation in few different places.

Comment: I think best way is a write your logic in validate method of serializer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
class YourSerializer(serializers.Serializer)
    start = serializers.DateTimeField()
    finish = serializers.DateTimeField()

    def validate(self, data):
        """
        Validation of start and end date.
        """
        start_date = data['start']
        end_date = data['finish']
        if not start_date and not end_date:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("at least one date input required.")
        if other logic:
            other logic stuff
        return data
```

This is better solution for you

Comment: I think you shoudl change the line "start_date = data['start']" to be something like "start = data['start'] if 'start' in data else None" because if data doesn't contain a "start" field, an error would be thrown on the line in question.

Comment: A better idea would be to do the following




(if not data.get('start') and not data.get('end'))

Answer (score 5):

IMO this is a better solution:

```
class YourSerializer(serializers.Serializer)
    start = serializers.DateTimeField(required=False)
    end = serializers.DateTimeField(required=False)

    def validate(self, data):
        """
        Validation of start and end date.
        """
        start_date = data.get('start', None)
        end_date = data.get('end', None)
        if not start_date and not end_date:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("at least one date input required.")
        if other logic:
            other logic stuff
        return data
```

Start and end dates should be set to `required=False` as neither of them is always required. Afterwards, in the `validate()` function, you should be getting the values using `.get()` function in order to prevent raising `KeyError()` because of a missing key.